# Is it legal to add to an overload set conditionally

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider we have function that accepts some base type:

```
void print(const base&);
```

We then have, defined in another header, a structure that inherits from `base`, call it `derived`. Finally in a third header we have an overload of `print` that accepts a `derived`. In total, we have this:

```
// header 1
struct base {};
void print(const base&);

// header 2
#include "header 1"
struct derived:base{};

// header 3
struct derived;
void print(const derived&);
```

It is important to note that the `print` functions are defined in different TUs. Now compare these two TUs:

```
// source 1
#include "header 2"

void foo() {
    derived d;
    print(d);
}

// source 2
#include "header 2"
#include "header 3"

void bar() {
    derived d;
    print(d);
}
```

The calls to `print` look the same, but the first source file calls `print(const base&)` while the second calls `print(const derived&)`. Is this behavior legal and mandated by the standard? Or did I at some point dip into UB?

What if `print` was a template function instead, so that we overloaded `print` with a non template method (disregard that the template method may be chosen over the non template as it may match better, assume that we overload it correctly), would the legality be altered?

Part of the reason for the question stems from wondering what are legal and sane sources of customization and what are not. The standard library tends towards partial/explicit specialization of class templates.

Comment: As you mentioned TU (translation unit), you are probably aware that every C++ source is compiled on its own. However, I would re-think this design - maintenance of such code can become a nightmare either if you want to touch this code later or somebody else wants...

Comment: I agree with you, but there are certain places where we do want user customization. I can point to something like specializing `tuple_element` or overloading `operator << (std::istream)` as examples, and was wondering on pure legality of this exact approach.

Comment: If you want to become sure (or illustrate) how the compiler "sees" the translation units - make a preprocess-only compile. (e.g. `g++ -E`) For sources like exposed in your sample code, this should be fine. If you `#include` standard headers, you might be shocked about the amount of code which comes out... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is legal, but fragile.

If your `foo` was in header as inline function, it would be problematic as you might then break ODR (One Definition Rule).

`foo` would then call `void print(const base&);` or `void print(const derived&);` depending of previous include.

`foo` might be rewritten as:

```
void foo() {
    derived d;
    print(static_cast<Base&>(d));
}
```

to be explicit on which overload to choose.

> What if print was a template function instead, so that we overloaded print

```
template <typename T> void print(const T&);
```

With overload, it is not problematic.

With specialization it would be, as `foo` and `bar` would use `print<derived>`, but using different definitions.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the template overload vs specialization part?

Comment: I mean that `void print(const base&);` vs `void print(const T&);` would just be the same case as with your initial snippet. Legal but fragile. With `void print(const T&);` (the primary template, with T = void print(const T&);`) vs `void print<derived>(const derived&);` (the specialization), it is problematic, as you have 2 methods `print<derived>` whereas only one is allowed (ODR).